# Use High Resolution Bullet Point Image for UL

Tags: html, css, bulletedlist

I need to use a 100 px wide bullet image for a ul, but then scale it down to 8px and have it behave like the normal ul bullet list.

```
ul.bg-img li {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
    background-size: 8px 8px;
 ...
}
```

The problem is that the bullet does not line up with the first row of content. If I put a heading tag and a paragraph inside the li, then the bullet displays in the middle of the li element or below it.

If I add a margin and padding to move it around, it does not work for variable line heights and amounts of content.

```
/* breaks when going to second line */
margin: 1.00em 0 0 -30px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
```

It should behave like the default bullets: aligned to top content.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/nqvfj004/

NOTE: I need to use a 100px high resolution bullet because this is for a webapp that exports the web preview to print.

Comment: What do you mean by high resolution? Bullet points as rendered by browsers work in any resolution.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using the `list-style-image` property?

Comment: By high resolution, I mean "print quality" or not a 1:1 pixel ratio. For example, the 100px image scaled down to 8px

Comment: In the fiddle, I did try list-style-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100); but I can't find a way to scale that down to 8px on render

Comment: You should be using an svg not a jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set `background-position` from top, shift position on large font elements

First, set your `background-position` to some value from the top, not the center. I prefer to use `calc(1em - 4px)` because this puts the `8px` tall image in the vertical middle of a standard `1em` font line. You can use `top` or another basic unit as a fallback for older browsers.

```
ul.bg-img li {
    ...
    background-position: left top;
    background-position: left calc(0.5em - 4px);
    ...
}
```

Next, you should adjust for elements whose font-size is larger than 1em. You can do this at least two ways:

1. Adjust for larger font-size elements that may appear on the first line by shifting their position up and applying a corresponding negative bottom margin.

   ```
   ul.bg-img li h1:first-child {
       position: relative;
       top: -0.25em;
       margin-bottom: -0.25em;
   }
   ```

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em; 
}
ul.bg-img {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.bg-img li {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
    background-size: 8px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-position: left calc(0.5em - 4px);
    margin: 1em 0 0 -30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
ul.bg-img li h1:first-child {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.25em;
    margin-bottom: -0.25em;
}
ul.bg-img li h2:first-child {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.1875em;
    margin-bottom: -0.1875em;
}
ul.bg-img li h3:first-child {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.125em;
    margin-bottom: -0.125em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Background Image on li</h3>

<ul class="bg-img">
    <li>
        <h1>Bullet lines up with H1</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Bullet lines up with H2</h2>
        <p>Paragraph on second line</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Bullet lines up with H3</h3>
        <span>Span on second line</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph on first line</p>
        <h3>H3 on second line</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Span on first line</span>
        <h3>H3 on second line</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph alone</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Span alone</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

2. Apply a fixed line-height to all direct children of list-items. Use `rem` here instead of `em`.

   ```
   ul.bg-img li>* {
       line-height: 1.25rem;
   }
   ```

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em; 
}
ul.bg-img {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.bg-img li {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
    background-size: 8px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-position: left calc(0.5rem - 4px);
    margin: 1em 0 0 -30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
ul.bg-img li>* {
    line-height: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<h3>Background Image on li</h3>

<ul class="bg-img">
    <li>
        <h1>Bullet lines up with H1</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Bullet lines up with H2</h2>
        <p>Paragraph on second line</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Bullet lines up with H3</h3>
        <span>Span on second line</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph on first line</p>
        <h3>H3 on second line</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Span on first line</span>
        <h3>H3 on second line</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph alone</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Span alone</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this is effective, I admit it is fairly convoluted. After seeing the other answers, I like the simplicity of @Brewal's solution.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work with IE8 too? I tried to use filter sizingMethod='scale' but that stretches the image across the <li>.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you may want to experiment with using `:before` to generate a pseudo-element that contains the background-image. Because you can specify width, height and position on it, then perhaps using IE's `sizingMethod='scale'` will yield better results.

Answer (score 1):

You should place it on the first element inside the `li` instead of the whole `li`. Try this selector :

```
ul.bg-img li *:first-child
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqvfj004/4/)

Comment: This is a smart approach, but you should change background-position so that the bullet isn't vertically centered if the first text node has to wrap: `background-position: 11px 0.5em;`

Comment: @gfullam Yes indeed. It need to be tweeked a bit more, but that was just for the idea. Thanks.

Comment: IE8 supports first-child. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Ho well, sorry. The background-size property is not supported in IE8. You could try this https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill#readme

Answer (score 0):

instead of background image please use: `list-style-image:url(http://placehold.it/100x100);` and see the result. you don't need to use background at all.

Comment: It needs to scale down to 8px for the web preview

Comment: if you want to do something like that so forget the ul li use a div: <div class="all"><div class="bullets"></div><div class="content"></div> . the go to css float left the bullets class and give your background also don't forget the display:inline-block; than the content float:left and display:inline-block. i hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an option because the WYSIWYG editor generates a standard ul. It outputs a list that is then exported for print too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background-position from top either for all Li element's or only first Li element.

For first Li:

```
ul.bg-img li:first-child {
background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
background-size: 8px 8px;
background-position: left 10px;  /* 10px is dummy value you can set as per your requirement. */
.....
}
```

For All Li:

```
ul.bg-img li {
background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
background-size: 8px 8px;
background-position: left 10px;  /* 10px is dummy value you can set as per your requirement. */
.....
}
```